# java: chained method call confusion

Tags: java, android

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
    .create();
```

I don't understand why I can call "setPosiveButton" from "setTitle" 's result.
I checked the API document. These 2 methods both belong to AlertDialog.Builder. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

So why it can be called this why?

Comment: Because such methods returns 'this'.

Comment: The API you linked to tells you why very clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Builder.setTitle() returns the Builder object. See the [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the very same document you linked. The returned object's description is:

> **Returns**
>   This Builder object to allow for chaining of calls to set methods

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an instance of Builder `return new AlertDialog.Builder()`. Those methods being called after invoking the constructor return the instance you just created. The method looks something like this:

```
public AlertDialog.Builder setTitle(String title) {
    //do something with title
    return this;
}
```

Thats why it works. Since the method returns the instance, and you can call methods directly from instances (you dont need a reference, you can do `new Class().method()`), this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of the "builder" design pattern. It is used to make constructing an object a little more easier. Rather than having a constructor with many parameters, or many different overloaded constructors, we use a builder instead. The result of any of the "set" methods in the builder returns the builder itself, so that we are gradually building up the content. In the end, when we have set all parameters that we want to set, we call "create" to actually instantiate an "AlertDialog".

Comment: The part about constructors is not true. Method chaining is not about constructors, it's about not repeating the method call on the same variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which part specifically?

Comment: If each method didn't return `this`, you could still use just one constructor. You would have to declare a variable, instantiate it, and make consecutive calls to subsequent methods using the variable.

Comment: Is what I said really not true? Or did you mean that that isnt the only place where builder pattern, or in general method chaining, is applied?

Comment: We can do the same thing by using a "struct" or "enum" too, right? :)  That is, how we handle something depends on the task at hand. I was answering the specific question about how the above can be done. I also elaborated by giving some context as to why it makes sense. I didnt want to bother explaining all different options (i.e. no-arg constructor with setters).

Comment: In what way, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51955/discussion-between-jordan-and-szymon)